# Trying to Add Vectors with Attached Smart Pointers

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

I am trying to improve my coding skills by using smart pointers to handle memory management and created a simple program to add the components of two 2D vector structs and save it to a third 2D vector struct.

The compiler is blowing up when I call the `addVec2()` function.

There aren't a lot of examples of actually passing smart pointers (that point to actual data structures rather than primitives) to functions.

Can someone please help solve this?

Thank you.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

#define ENDL "\n"


struct vec2
{
    int a;
    int b;
};


template<typename T>
void addVec2(T *v1, T *v2, T *v3)
{
    v3->a = v1->a + v2->a;
    v3->b = v1->b + v2->b;
}


int main() {

    std::unique_ptr<vec2> p_vec1(new vec2);
    p_vec1->a = 1;
    p_vec1->b = 2;

    std::unique_ptr<vec2> p_vec2(new vec2);
    p_vec2->a = 3;
    p_vec2->b = 7;

    std::unique_ptr<vec2> p_vec3(new vec2);


    addVec2<std::unique_ptr<vec2>>(p_vec1, p_vec2, p_vec3);

    return 0;
}
```

I have even tried to use templates to try and solve the problem of it complaining that ONLY `unique_ptr` types can be fed into the function instead of any type of pointer that still points to the same type (`vec2`), but this still doesn't work.

Comment: `std::unique_ptr` is not copyable, so you can't pass it by value to `addVec2`. But you don't need smart pointers at all in this case - just declare the `vec2` objects on the stack and make `addVec2` accept `T&` arguments.

Comment: My recommendation is to not see the smart pointers only as a kind of self-deleting pointers, but rather in terms of *ownership*. And with this in mind, do you *really* need pointers here? While it might be good for just simple exercises, the example you show doesn't really need pointers at all, you could use plain objects directly together with references.

Comment: As for the call `addVec2<std::unique_ptr<vec2>>(p_vec1, p_vec2, p_vec3)`, the compiler can deduce template types from arguments, so only `addVec2(p_vec1, p_vec2, p_vec3)` should be needed.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the support! Although the example is a bit too simple for something like a smart pointer, I wanted to learn how to give better memory management for more complex objects and figure out how to pass them through functions without the compiler freaking out.

The concept of smart pointers and their proper usage is new for me, so I'm trying to figure out some proof of concept tests.

Comment: 1st problem: unnecessary use of raw pointers instead of references: `vec2 operator+(vec2 const&, vect2 const&);`. 2nd problem wrong parameter for unnecessary explicit template argument `<unique_ptr<T>>`. 3rd problem: wrong use of `unique_ptr` instead of raw pointers; the `get()` accessor is needed. 4th problem: `std::make_unique` must replace `new`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are passing `std::unique_ptr` to `addVec2`, and it's not `T*`. Simply changing your arguments of `addVec2` from pointers to references can solve the problem.

```
template<typename T>
void addVec2(T &v1, T &v2, T &v3)
{
    v3->a = v1->a + v2->a;
    v3->b = v1->b + v2->b;
}

int main() {
    // ...
    addVec2<std::unique_ptr<vec2>>(p_vec1, p_vec2, p_vec3);
}
```

But I'd suggest you to pass a `vec2&`, not `std::unique_ptr<vec2>&`. So it's better to write:

```
template<typename T>
void addVec2(const T &v1, const T &v2, T &v3)
{
    v3.a = v1.a + v2.a;
    v3.b = v1.b + v2.b;
}

int main() {
    // ...
    addVec2(*p_vec1, *p_vec2, *p_vec3);
}
```

Note that the type parameter of addVec2 can be deduced. And `const` is added to `v1` and `v2` since we do not modify them.

Answer (score 1):

The problem:
`addVec2` accepts the arguments by value. But `std::unique_ptr` is **non-copyable** so you cannot pass them by value.

An immediate fix, which I don't recommend, could be to accept the arguments **by reference** (const reference for the input):

```
template<typename T>
//-------------vvvvvvv-------vvvvvvv-------v----
void addVec2(T const & v1, T const & v2, T & v3)
{
    v3->a = v1->a + v2->a;
    v3->b = v1->b + v2->b;   
}
```

But in this case you don't actually need smart pointers.
You can declare the `vec2` objects on the stack and accepts them by reference in `addVec2`:

```
struct vec2
{
    int a;
    int b;
};

template<typename T>
void addVec2(T const & v1, T const & v2, T & v3)
{
    v3.a = v1.a + v2.a;
    v3.b = v1.b + v2.b;
}

int main() {

    vec2 v1{ 1, 2 };
    vec2 v2{ 3, 7 };
    vec2 v3;
    addVec2(v1, v2, v3);
}
```

Note that when I called `addVec2` I didn't specify the template parameter type - the compile can deduce it from the arguments.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that you confuse smart pointers with plain non-owning non-smart pointers...

As an argument `T* v1`, the compiler and the function expects a *pointer* to a `std::unique_ptr<vec2>` object.

So your call should really be `addVec2(&p_vec1, &p_vec2, &p_vec3)`. And inside the function you need to use e.g. `(*v1)->a`, etc.

Or update the function arguments to be *references* instead of pointers.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, that along with what many others are saying cleared up that concern since I was starting to think that each function could specifically only handle one type of pointer.

Answer (score 0):

std::unique_ptr can not copy.
so you can use std::shared_ptr instead of std::unique_ptr

or

```
template<typename T>
void addVec2(T &v1, T &v2, T &v3)
{
    v3->a = v1->a + v2->a;
    v3->b = v1->b + v2->b;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to dig around a bit but found this tutorial website very useful & it answered my question enough for me to get a usable solution, although I have no idea if this is the 'right' way to do things.

https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/stdunique_ptr/

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

#define ENDL "\n"


struct vec2
{
    int a;
    int b;
};


void addVec2( vec2 *v1, vec2 *v2, vec2 *v3)
{
    v3->a = v1->a + v2->a;
    v3->b = v1->b + v2->b;
}


int main() {

    auto ptr1{ std::make_unique<vec2>() };
    ptr1->a = 1;
    ptr1->b = 2;

    auto ptr2{ std::make_unique<vec2>() };
    ptr2->a = 3;
    ptr2->b = 7;

    auto ptr3{ std::make_unique<vec2>() };


    addVec2(ptr1.get(), ptr2.get(), ptr3.get());

    std::cout << ptr3->a << "," << ptr3->b << ENDL;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Although it can work, it is not the best way to solve this problem. See my answer for more details.